# SWF to Screenshot or Thumbnail on Linux

Tags: flash, thumbnails

whats the best way to get a screenshot or thumbnail of a SWF file on linux?
Need something i can build into a app.

thanks

Comment: Screenshot a file? Do you want a screenshot of what the .swf actually looks like when it's being played? or just the raw binary bits or its file icon?

Comment: of what the swf would like when its being played